# Is there an XPath concatenation operation similar to System.IO.Path.Combine()?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

[System.IO.Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) allows to combine paths like `C:\Users\Peter` and `Desktop\photo.jpg` into `C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\photo.jpg`. Smart handling of path separators during the concatenation is one of its main benefits: concatenation always works well regardless of whether `\` is present at the end of the first path or not.

Is there some similar mechanism available for Xpath?

Expected behavior:
`/Customer/Order` + `LineItem/Description/text()` => `/Customer/Order/LineItem/Description/text()`

Comment: What's the point of concatenating two path expressions if XPath has no dynamic evaluation?

Comment: I wish I could upvote @Kirill's answer, which was automatically and mistakenly labeled as not providing an answer. Mike McCaughan, let the votes decide. Low quality, or "of less use than it could be", is not the same as "not an answer."

Comment: @LarsH Even if it is technically correct, an "it's not possible" answer should at least provide some substantiation about _why_ it's not possible. Otherwise, it doesn't fit the criteria for an answer and belongs here in the comments section. Mike McCaughan said essentially the same thing 9 hours ago.

Comment: @MaxToro - why do you think that static/dynamic evaluation matters? 
`System.IO.Path.Combine()` is pretty static, too. It is not checking actual paths in filesystem, it just saves you some syntax handling.

Comment: @JLRishe: can you cite the criteria you're referring to? I'm seeing a leap over the gap from the well-justified "It would be a better answer if it did X" to "It's not an answer".

Comment: @LarsH Well, the **Answer the question** paragraph [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) sort of agrees with me. Another thing is that Kiril's answer doesn't answer the question at all. I know OP's wording was "Is there some similar mechanism...", but I'm fairly sure OP was actually asking for a way to combine XPaths and not a yes/no response. If there's no way to do so, the answer should at least provide some substantiation rather than a blunt "no".

Comment: @JLRishe – well,I can implement combining Xpaths by myself. I just wanted to know whether I'm not overlooking something built-in. The answer *"there is none"* actually helped me much at the moment. On the other hand, someone could still add more explanative answer beneficial for the readers, either recommending some effective technique or at least saying something authoritative like *"I know well all the XML libraries in .NET 4.5 and I can confirm there is nothing like you requested."* It would be definitely more helpful than plain *"there is nothing"*. There is still possibility open for this

Comment: @JLRishe: the paragraph you linked to says 'it *should* also include “try this instead”' (emphasis added) ... which agrees with "It would be a better answer if it did X" but doesn't support the leap to "It's not an answer." (That paragraph also says brevity is acceptable.) Your comment "should at least provide some substantiation" is true, but again doesn't justify "It's not an answer."

Comment: @LarsH I guess we'll need to agree to disagree. As I see it, that "should" is defining a necessary criterion for what kind of answers meet the quality standards of this site. Answers that do not meet those standards "should" not stay. I also think that the remaining 75% of my last comment, to which you didn't respond, makes a pretty good case for why it's not an answer.

Comment: @JLRishe: I thought the OP's comment answered that part: he *was* asking for a yes/no response and the "no" response was very helpful. On the other point, if you argue that all the answers that don't fulfill every "should" in the FAQ are not answers, then many useful and accepted answers are not answers.

Comment: P.S. According to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272926/423105, Kirill's answer would qualify for neither "low quality" ('can't possibly be fixed') nor "not an answer" (it is clearly *an attempt* to answer the question). Instead, it should at worst have been downvoted (with a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the .net tag, thus I derive you're stuck with XPath 1.0.

Concatenation of a fixed number of atomic strings is easy in **XPath 1.0** by using `concat($string1, $string2, ..., $stringN)`, for example

```
concat('/Customer/Order', '/', 'LineItem/Description/text()')
```

Yet, this requires knowledge whether a tailing slash is present or not. XPath 1.0 does not really know case distinctions and has very limited string manipulation capabilities, you're stuck with rather ugly predicate hacks and repeated strings.

```
concat('/Customer/Order',
       '/'['/' != substring('/Customer/Order', string-length('/Customer/Order'))],
       'LineItem/Description/text()'
)
```

Using **XPath 2.0** using the newly introduced `ends-with(...)` function and if-then-else clauses, you could do something like

```
concat('/Customer/Order',
       if (ends-with('/Customer/Order', '/'))
       then ''
       else '/',
       'LineItem/Description/text()'
)
```

or a little bit shorter

```
concat('/Customer/Order',
       '/'[not(ends-with('/Customer/Order', '/'))],
       'LineItem/Description/text()'
)
```

and finally using a hack with a single item loop to remove the requirement of repeating the variable:

```
for $string in '/Customer/Order'
return 
  concat($string,
         '/'[not(ends-with($string, '/'))],
         'LineItem/Description/text()'
  )
```

**Conclusion:** Don't consider "complex" string manipulation in XPath, especially not XPath 1.0. It looks much better with XPath 2.0, and is fun using XQuery.